# Выбор без нажатия кнопки

Tags: javascript, html

```
<form action="2" method="post" class='left'>
<label>Тема:</label>
<select>
<option value="2">1</option>
<option selected="selected" value="4">2</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Эта формочка, как вы уже поняли выбор 1или2, но не хватает кнопки ОК, чтоб отправить, как сделать -  так скрыть эту кнопку чтоб не надо было нажимать на неё? а чтоб просто выбрал 1или2 и автоматом запрос послался? помогите плс...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
jQuery:
$('form.left option').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
 jQuery(function($) {
 $('form.left option').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
});
не получилось =(

Comment: решил проблемку через добавление в select - onchange="document.forms[0].submit();"

Comment: Тогда уж лучше добавить

   onchange="this.form.submit()"

за-субмитит текущую форму